# Why did someone in my server find a ton of drops all at once?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I was playing *TF2* and all of a sudden someone found a lot of drops all at once:

[image: animated GIF of someone finding a lot of drops all at once]

How did he get these all at once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The person in question may have been inactive for a long period of time, so he did not open the window that shows his drops. His item drops will have accumulated if he was dying periodically due to idling. So he would have opened the window after being AFK and recieved all dropped items.

Comment: Quick note:  It looks like this isn't the case within this one instance, but otherwise, this answer is the usually correct one.  Based on the item drops, it looks like the player captured in the picture used a external tool to "complete" achievements and get retroactively rewarded for them.

Answer (score 9):

All of the items dropped are achievement reward items.

This is a case where the person used SAM or a community server with the correct plugins, to unlock all of the achievements with item drops. They then joined your server and got the item notification which they acknowledged, showing the drops.

Comment: This checks out.  The part that gives it away is that the player in question receives a "Haunted Metal Scrap" which is limited to only be earned during the Halloween events.  Even if the player logged off at some point during the event, that item isn't a random drop and would of required interaction with the game. (So it couldn't appear in that "loot in waiting" queue.

Comment: @NBN-Alex Actually, you CAN earn it outside of Halloween.  Better yet, in 2013 Valve updated the game to treat Halloween maps as if Halloween mode were enabled.  So, as long as you're playing cp_manor_event and there are 10+ players, he'll spawn.

Comment: The tricky part is being close enough to melee the Horseless Headless Horsemann during his death animation.